# How do I know if my bag is full?

Tags: pokemon-go

When I go to Pokestops, sometimes it tells me my bag is full, even though I'll only have about 20 pokeballs and about the same number of great balls.

Is bag fullness dictated by the total number of items or is there a cap per item?

Answer (score 20):

Click on the red pokeball in the bottom middle of the screen. Then click on items and on the top of that screen it should say xxx/350. Bag size fullness is only dictated by total number of items, you can have 350 pokeballs if you wanted.

Comment: Ah, thanks for pointing that out. Looks like I gotta get rid of some revives and potions then.

Comment: FYI it seems that "fullness" indicator is a suggestion only, I've got 373 of 350 slots used.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr It's not, however if you are under when you gain new items and you go over, it will still let you keep what you got. You will not be able to get anything else until you go below 350. You probably leveled up and it gave you a bunch of items.

Comment: You can also upgrade the storage of your bag by purchasing an upgrade from the shop (I believe the max capacity after purchasing all the upgrades is 900?)

Comment: @Ben, max capacity is 1000.

Comment: @Dom I would imagine especially that level-up bonuses would not be subject to the item cap. It'd suck otherwise...

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I can confirm that it is not capped. I leveled up with less than 10 slots left, then had to throw a ton of stuff away before I could get anything from stops since I was at like 540/500 items...