# Why does it say my bag is full at a Pokestop when I have no Pokeballs left?

Tags: pokemon-go

I try to spin a Pokestop, it says my bag is full but I don't have any Pokeballs left. Why is this happening?

Comment: See [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/275569/how-do-i-know-if-my-bag-is-full?rq=1)

Comment: The item count is also affected by potions / revives etc. Maybe you have hundreds of potions in your inventory. If you dont need them just throw them away

Answer (score 11):

**The items are not limited in quantity, as long you have free space** on your bag, so doesn't have to be pokeballs that will fill the bag. *(Which means for example, Potions can fill the whole bag space, thus leaving no space for your other items like pokeballs.)*

Your bag contains all inventory items, while pokemons that have been caught have a separate storage. Inventory items include:

- Pokeballs
- Potions
- A Camera
- Incubators
- Revives
- Incenses
- Berries
- Lure Modules

Each item will count as 1 space in your bag.

[image]

**How to have more space for your bag?**

1. Click the Trash Bin icon beside the item you want to remove, then input a quantity of that item you want to be removed
2. Upgrade your bag.

[image]

Comment: At around level 15ish, normal potions are nearly worthless since you need at least 3-4 per revived competitive Pokemon (800+ CP), so you can throw almost all of them out if all your Pokemon are alive.  If you plan on assaulting a gym, you can save up revives and just keep slamming the place.  Otherwise, chuck a bunch of them for balls if you are going on a catching spree.  If you got G-Balls, use them on 200+ CP pokemon just because you'll get more.  I find I don't need more than 15-20 if i'm riding on a bus since I'll keep hitting stops.  In a park you may need about 50ish for 30 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Pokeballs are not the only item in your Inventory.

Potions, Revives, and Razz Berries also count towards your bag count.

To clear out your bag, you can tap the Pokeball and select your Bag. From there, hit the Trash Can to get rid of any excess items.